# Linux MySQL Optimization

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Hey we moved to a much bigger Server and we want to optimize our performance from MySQL.
Does anyone know how to increase the performance? Or like a config generator or something like that. I don't find much about on the internet

Comment: Having said that, there's a lot of tweaking you can do, to use your hardware in the best possible way.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful information includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

- Throwing hardware at a MySQL performance problem rarely helps.
- Only occasionally can anything be tuned (in `my.cnf`) to speed up things.
- Usually performance issues stem from lack of a good index or a poorly formulated query.
- There is no fully automated tool.

For help with tuning and slow queries, see:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

It is unclear whether this belongs in dba.stackexchange.com (for hardware and tuning) or stackoverflow.com (for indexes and queries).  If you tag it with `[mysql]` and `[performance]`, I will see it.